# Can't save videos on my wamp(php)

Tags: php, ajax, wamp

Hello I'm new in web development and try not asking simple questions.
I'm trying to save uploaded files with ajax to my wamp using php but my code only allows .jpg and .doc files to be saved.
Here's the code with the upload button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>

<input name="file" id="file" type="file" />
<br /><br />
<progress id="progress"></progress>

<script>

var fileInput = document.querySelector('#file'),
    progress = document.querySelector('#progress');

fileInput.onchange = function() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', 'community.php');

    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        progress.value = e.loaded;
        progress.max = e.total;
    };

    xhr.onload = function() {
        var uploadStatus = document.getElementById("finish");
        document.getElementById('finish').innerHTML = 'Upload done !';      
    };

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);

    xhr.send(form);

};

</script>

<p id="finish">
</p>
```

And here's the code of the treatment of the POST request:

```
$error    = NULL;
$filename = NULL; 

if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] === 0) {

    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetpath = getcwd() . '/' . $filename; // On stocke le chemin où enregistrer le fichier

    // On déplace le fichier depuis le répertoire temporaire vers $targetpath
    if (@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetpath)) { // Si ça fonctionne
        $error = 'OK';
        try
        {
                $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
                echo "it worked" ;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
        }
        $result= $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $bdd->exec("INSERT INTO videos(Name) VALUES('$result')");
        echo $result;
    } 

    else 
    { // Si ça ne fonctionne pas
        $error = "Failure of uploading";
    }
} else 
    {
    $error = 'No videos uploaded!';
    }


  if(isset($_POST["community.php"]))
      {

          $Location = $_POST["community.php"];
          FileFunc($Location);
      }

      function FileFunc($Location){

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Location);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $myFile = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
 $file = 'myFile.pdf';
 file_put_contents($file, $myFile);
 }
```

And one line of javascript at the end:

```
window.top.window.uploadEnd("<?php echo $error; ?>", "<?php echo $filename; ?>");
```

The weird thing is in $file = 'myFile.pdf'; it doesn't work with .pdf files and only only .doc files are saved. When I put 'myFile.jpg' , pictures are saved in the wamp but when I try any video extension it doesn't work...

I tried using  before for uploading and saving a file and it never saves files above 10mb, could anyone confirm me if it's normal?

Thank you for your time.

UPDATE at 15.00 gmt time :
After my recent comment on this matter here's the same problem with Iframe:

The code with the button:

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" target="uploadFrame" method="post">
    <label for="uploadFile">Image :</label>
    <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" />
    <br /><br />
    <input id="uploadSubmit" type="submit" value="Upload !" />
</form>
```

The server answer (lighter version of the previous upload.php):

Comment: of course it's normal to not save files larger than a `limited` amount... you need to modify the ini file of your wamp and add: memory_limit = 96M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M.... or any other value after your needs... that's why it's limited... also make sure you read file from js as binary and not file

Comment: You're checking `$_FILES['file']['error']` for `0`, but if it's not you're ignoring the actual value which tells you what went wrong, and printing a generic error message. Read the section in the PHP manual on [error codes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). In your case I'd guess your video files are larger than the maximum upload size limit set in `php.ini`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies.-HellBaby : I changed the settings on the file that is in bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini all of them to 100M and it still doesn't work ... I tried also using the <iframe> coding and it's exactly the same thing ... (I can't put the quote of it when I edit my original post ...) I will look at reading file from js as binary (I don't know how to but I will search for it) -Mike W : thanks for your advice this should surely come in handy and as I said to HellBaby I changed the settings still same prob on both coding... Thanks again guys.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and your code allows malicious users to scribble **ANY** file of their choosing **ANYWHERE** on your server. This code is a security disaster.

Comment: Thanks Marc B, once I make it work I will look after the security such as htmlspecialchars, one thing at a time doesn't make giving up ^^

Comment: Mike W: I checked the 9 error messages with the <iframe> code and it's none of these ... when it's a big file it eithers never give a result of the request or it says it's none of these errors. As for the xmlhttprequest I can't test it as I haven't find the extension of  $file = 'myFile.pdf'for big videos such as mp4... still stuck despite looking all over the website.

Comment: I finally just sorted it.

The thing is that when I did a search on windows xp, it showed the php.ini on the folder php 5.4.3 (the one I kept changing), symfony  and apache 2.2.22

I didn't carefully noticed that the apache 2.2.22 php.ini and the php 5.4.3 were different and I noticed the difference after finding on google you can go straight to the correct php.ini by click on your wamp then php then php.ini .

Weird thing is that the php.ini on the wamp menu is in php when the actual file is on apache 2.2.22 directory ... Thank you all